# Datatable Scroll Enable when it dont need

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is my datatable declaration. I have a table n number of columns some times it will come just two column that time also scoll will enable. It will make some irritating table.  How to avoid scroll when it dont needs and i want fixed column of first column.

```
var shTable = jQuery('#example').DataTable({
                scrollX:        true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                bScrollAutoCss: false,
                paging:         true,
                responsive: true,
                aaSorting : []  
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
var shTable = jQuery('#example').DataTable({
                scrollX:        true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                bScrollAutoCss: false,
                paging:         false,
                scrollY:        200px,
                responsive: true,
                aaSorting : []  
            });
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. i dont need vertical scroll.. I need horizontal scroll when more number of columns come thats it.